# How to disable cipher suites in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls1.2

Please suggest me to disable following cipher suites(TLS 1.2) in Nginx web server.

- RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Thank you

Comment: To find out ow to configure ciphers for nginx would have been a quick search away. Please invest more effort into your question or show what you've tried and where you've failed.